# Understanding closures in for-loops

Tags: javascript, for-loop, closures

I'm confused why the option 1 prints out '6', 5 times, whereas the option 2 prints out 0,1,2,3,4,5. Shouldn't the first one print out like the option 2?

Option 1:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i <= 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(i);
    });
}
```

Option 2:

```
for (var i = 0 ; i <= 5; i++) {
    doThis(function() {
        console.log(i);
    });
}
function doThis(a) {
    a();
}
```

Comment: Does the answer to this explain it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: Basically because the option 1 is async. A way to avoid this is wrapping it with `(function(i){ /* code */ })(i);`

Comment: No, I'm still confused. I'm just replacing setTimeout with a another function, but it's producing a different result.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia can you dig little deeper into what async really means?

Comment: it's because `setTimeout` is executed after the for loop has finished and the value of `i` is `5` then.

Comment: @jcubic why is the setTimeout executed after the for loop?

Comment: It's because setTimeout add function to the queue that is executed after current task is finished and the current task is for loop so it execute after it's finish.

Comment: Because [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) was designed to do that.

Comment: Check this video What the heck is the event loop anyway?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: awesome thanks! here's a more detailed explanation: http://brackets.clementng.me/post/24150213014/example-of-a-javascript-closure-settimeout-inside

Comment: I think I'm late to the party, it is one of the main differences of javascript with other languages (and one of the reasons why it's so powerful). Please read about the topic "asynchronous javascript", since it's a big topic and difficult to explain in a comment.